# Using the 'TODAY' function

Tags: excel

My spreadsheet is to show me how many days active a certain field has been. 
For this I am trying to find a formula which will automatically take the entered date from one cell and deduct it from "todays" date.

As an example I have used =DATEVALUE("22/04/2017")-TODAY() - and although this works, i am unable to drag the formula down into other cells, to auto populate when a date has been entered/ amended. I'm having to enter the formula above every time, and if the date changes, as an example from the 22/04/2017 to the 20/04/2017, I would have to manually amend the formula too. How can I get it just pick up the date in that particular cell and deduct "today" from it?

Sorry if i'm rambling, I just don't know if I'm explaining myself properly.

Thank you

Comment: why dont you refer the cell instead of entering the value manually

Comment: Just as @SivaprasathV said you can use formula like `=DATEVALUE(A1)-TODAY()` assuming dates are in `Column A`, then drag/copy down the formula as required.

Comment: thank you, but when I do that it brings up #VALUE!

Comment: Typically, '*how many days active a certain field has been*' would be a positive number (i.e. the number of days). Reverse the subtrahend and minuend to get a positive integer; e.g. `=today()-A3`

Comment: Then the 'date' in A3 is not a real date. Is it right-aligned or left aligned in the cell? (doesn't count if you changed the alignment manually) What do you get with `=text(A3, "dd-mm-yyyy;;;[red]\n\o\t\ \a\ \d\a\t\e")` ?

Comment: Reversing it works! Thank you so much!!

Comment: Do you know how I would then add to 'TODAY()-A3', to make it not count blank cells which have not yet had dates put in? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Typically, 'how many days active a certain field has been' would be a positive number (i.e. the number of days). Reverse the subtrahend and minuend to get a positive integer like this,

```
=today()-a3
```

To avoid getting 5/15/2017 or 42,870 as the result when A3 is blank, check to see if there is something in A3 before attempting subtraction.

```
=if(len(a3), today()-a3, text(,))
```